# Need to format number using regex (Cool Tool android app - cpu temp)

Tags: regex

The tool I am using is written in JavaScript, but I have no access to the JS code.

I am trying to foramt a number with regex only. For example, initial value is `25400`.  I would like to get `25.4` (remove the zeros and insert a comma, or dot).

So, need to get this using regex.
After a lot of searches, i have found something close to my case:

RegEx:

```
(\d{2})(?=\d)
```

Replacement Pattern:

```
$1.
```

But here, i get 25.400

What kind of regex i need to format this value to get 25.4? (comma or dot is the same).

**Right working regex: (\d+)(\d{1})(\d{2})**

**Replacement Pattern: $1.$2**

[image]

Hope in your help, thanks a lot!

Comment: "need to get this using regex" yeah, but why? Can't you just divide by 100 and round it?

Comment: Why Regex? Divide it by 100 and `toFixed(1)`

Comment: Look the edit... now you understand better...

Comment: @Devilix If you cannot use JS *code*, do not add the `javascript` or `jquery` tags, or at least mention that in the question (better, at the very beginning)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That app use javascript code

Comment: There are many more cases actually. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3krmjo/1), does it work as you expect?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it seems to be working... but i will get even 25.0? Or 25. ?

Comment: Wait, do you mean to say you *only* need to match and handle 5-digit strings? Can they have leading `0`s? What about `00000`?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regex here, try with;

```
'25400'.replace(/(\d{2})([1-9]+)0*/, '$1.$2')
// "25.4"
```

However for `25000` it will give `25.`.

It's recommended to divide this value by 100 and round as mentioned by @RoryMcCrossan and @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: You regex works! But why if the value is 25000 i can't get 25.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the initial number is 25400 and you want 25.4, divide the initial number by 1000 not 100 and use toFixed (1);

```js
function myFunction(){
 var initnum = "25400";
    var n = initnum/1000;
    n = n.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
Initial number is 25400
<br />
Click to get new number
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

if you want to use regex then hsz's answer works and try this if you want .0 `replace(/^(\d{2})([0-9]+)0*/, '$1.$2')` just trim it out after, this regex will return 25.000 if you have 25000

```html
initial number is 25000
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
myFunction();
function myFunction() {
 var initnum = "25000";
    var n = initnum.replace(/^(\d{2})([0-9]+)0*/, '$1.$2');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "new number from regex is "+n;
}
</script>
```

Comment: in my case i can't use your solution... thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you try @hsz's answer with a little adjustment to get .0?
.replace(/^(\d{2})([0-9]+)0*/, '$1.$2');

 Wiktor Stribiżew's answer will work unless you have some number after 0 like 22005

Comment: in this way i get 25.200 :(

Comment: Try this **/^(\d{2})([0-9])0*/, '$1.$2'**, this **/^(\d{2})([0-9]{1})([0-9]+)*/, '$1.$2'**, or this **(/^(\d{2})([0-9]{1})([0-9]+)*/, '$1.$2$3');**

Comment: the right working regex was (\d+)(\d{1})(\d{2}) $1.$2